# Flink: Access Key in RichMapFunction applied on KeyedStream to handle stream keyed by Option

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I would like to handle `None` as a key case when I apply a `RichMapFunction` to a keyed stream.

For example I have a case class like this:

```
case class Foo(a: Option[String], b: Int, acc: Option[Int] = None)
```

`acc` is the field I would like to compute with my `map`.

I would like to apply a stateful map on a stream, so I have a `RichMapFunction` (for example it's an accumulator):

```
class Accumulator extends RichMapFunction[Foo, Foo] {

  private var sum: ValueState[Int] = _

  override def map(input: Foo): Foo = {

    val newAcc = Option(sum.value()) match {
      case None => input.b
      case Some(x) => x + input.b
    }
    sum.update(newAcc)
    Foo(input.a, input.b, Some(newAcc))
  }

  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    sum = getRuntimeContext.getState(
      new ValueStateDescriptor[Int]("accumulator", createTypeInformation[Int])
    )
  }
}
```

Then, my pipeline is executed with:

```
object ExampleAccumulator extends App {

  val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

  env.fromElements(Foo(Some("a"), 1, None), Foo(Some("a"), 2, None), Foo(None, 10, None), Foo(None, 6, None))
    .keyBy(_.a)
    .map(new Accumulator())
    .print()

  env.execute("ExampleAccumulator")
}
```

The ouput is:

```
Foo(Some(a),1,Some(1))
Foo(Some(a),2,Some(3))
Foo(None,10,Some(10))
Foo(None,6,Some(16))
```

But I would like to get `None` in `acc` when key is `None`.

Is it possible to get the key in RichMapFunction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported for now. 
The key can be aquired by getCurrentKey() method in KeyContext class, which is not exposed in RichMapFunction. However, Flink internally provides the KeyedProcessFunction that can return key in the parameter Context. I believe this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems the right thing for me even if I also would like to keep the concept of one input / one output of the `map`. It will be ok for now :)

Comment: @Thomas, Sorry I don't know why I can't use markdown to attach the source codes here. You can check the process function in org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.KeyedStream.

Answer (score 1):

You could access the keys through values of the `Foo`, via `KeySelector` API, Scala workaround:

```
val selector = scalaKeyedStream
  .javaStream 
  .asInstanceOf[org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.KeyedStream]
  .getKeySelector

scalaKeyedStream.map(in => selector.getKey(in))
```

You need to cast Scala Stream to Java because there is no `getKeySelector` method in Scala API, [details](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11226?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=16729620#comment-16729620).